# plugin iCheck não desativa todas as checkbox

Tags: jquery

Boas,
estou com o problema de que tenho 6 checkbox mas só podem seleccionar no máximo 2 antes de submeter o formulário. O acontece é que ao clickar na terceira box ele da a mensagem e limpa as duas anteriores e a terceira fica seleccionada, e não consigo desseleccionar na totalidade das 5 checkbox com o plugin do iCkeck.

```js
 $('.selcheck').on('ifChecked', function(event){
  
  if ($('.selcheck').filter(':checked').length > 2 ) {
   
   alert('Só é permitido escolher 2 opções.');
      
   $('#d1, #d2, #d3, #d4, #d5, #d6').iCheck('uncheck');
   
  }
 
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id='d1' type='checkbox' class='selcheck'/>
<input id='d2' type='checkbox' class='selcheck'/>
<input id='d3' type='checkbox' class='selcheck'/>
<input id='d4' type='checkbox' class='selcheck'/>
<input id='d5' type='checkbox' class='selcheck'/>
```

**Solução:**

```
    $('.selcheck').on('ifChecked', function(event){

    var limpa = 0;

    if ($('.selcheck').filter(':checked').length > 2 ) {

        alert('Só é permitido escolher 2 opções.');

        limpa = 1;

    }

    $(function() {

        if (limpa == 1){
            $('.selcheck').iCheck('uncheck');
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Pelo que entendi de seu problema, não acho necessário o uso do plugin `iCheck` somente para desmarcar as checkbox. No código que atualizei eu deixei uma instrução para não deixar o terceiro checkbox marcado e para desmarcar todos quando atingir o limite de marcação dos checkbox - seguindo a sua intenção ao utilizar o `iCheck`.

```js
$(function() {

  $('.selcheck').click(function(event) {

    const $checkboxs = $('.selcheck');

    if ($checkboxs.filter(':checked').length > 2) {
      alert('Só é permitido escolher 2 opções.');

      $(this).prop('checked', false); // Desmarcar elemento atual
      //$checkboxs.prop('checked', false); // Desmarcar todos os elementos

      //$('#d1, #d2, #d3, #d4, #d5, #d6').iCheck('uncheck');
    }

  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id='d1' type='checkbox' class='selcheck' />
<input id='d2' type='checkbox' class='selcheck' />
<input id='d3' type='checkbox' class='selcheck' />
<input id='d4' type='checkbox' class='selcheck' />
<input id='d5' type='checkbox' class='selcheck' />
```

Comment: Viva eu uso o iCheck não só para desmarcar mas também pelo css

Comment: E qual o erro que o `iCheck` gerou?

Comment: vitor não deu nenhum erro, ao clicar na 3 caixa, depois da mensagem limpa as duas caixas selecionadas e a 3 caixa fica selecionada.

Comment: A solução que postei não resolve o seu problema?

Comment: Viva não resolveu, mas ja consegui resolver obrigado.

Answer (score -1):

Olá, fiz de duas formas, com javascript puro (sempre bom saber) e com jQuery.

PS: Atualizei o exemplo para demonstrar como seria feito com o iCheck.

PS2: o iCheck não renderizou corretamente os checkboxes então fiz um timer para ir checkando um a um, dessa forma o evento é chamado e o código verifica a contagem e desmarca todos caso necessário, resetando a contagem.

```js
// Exemplo com JS apenas..
/*
const checkList = document.querySelectorAll('[name=selcheck]');

Array.prototype.forEach.call(checkList, function(check) {
  check.addEventListener('change', function(evt) {
    var checked = Array.prototype.filter.call(checkList, function(c) {
      return c.checked;
    });
    
    if(checked.length > 2) {
      alert("É permitido selecionar apenas 2 items.");
      checked.forEach(function(c) { c.checked = false });
    }
  });
});
*/


// Exemplo jQuery
/*
$('input[name=selcheck]').on('change', function(evt) {
  var checkedList = $('input[name=selcheck]:checked');
  if(checkedList.length > 2) {
    alert("só pode selecionar 2..");
    $(checkedList).prop('checked', false);
  }
});
*/

// Exemplo iCheck
let checked = 0;
var checkboxes = $('input[name=selcheck]');
checkboxes.iCheck();
checkboxes.on('ifChecked', function(evt) {
  let checkedChecks = checkboxes.filter('input:checked');
  
  console.log(checkedChecks.length);
  
  if(checkedChecks.length > 2) {
    alert('only 2 allowed..');
    checked = 0;
    checkedChecks.iCheck('uncheck');
  }
});

setInterval(function() {
  let checkbox = $(checkboxes[checked++]);
  checkbox.iCheck('check');
}, 3000);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/iCheck/1.0.2/icheck.min.js"></script>

<input id='d1' name='selcheck' type='checkbox' class='selcheck' />
<input id='d2' name='selcheck' type='checkbox' class='selcheck' />
<input id='d3' name='selcheck' type='checkbox' class='selcheck' />
<input id='d4' name='selcheck' type='checkbox' class='selcheck' />
<input id='d5' name='selcheck' type='checkbox' class='selcheck' />
```

Comment: Dessa forma eu sei que resulta mas usando o plugin do iCheck já não resulta

Comment: @SergioTeixeira veja agora com o ultimo exemplo.

Comment: Amigo dessa forma não esta resultando, porque ele não limpa a 3 caixa quando clico nela, e não posso ter um tempo visto ser um formulário e pode demorar algum tempo ate ser submetido.

Comment: O exemplo com o tempo foi somente para fins de demonstração pois os checkboxes ficaram invisiveis quando habilitei o iCheck no código da resposta. Dessa forma, mesmo sem enxergar os items é possível ver o funcionamento. Para seu código de produção você não iria incluir o setInterval e o código referente a ele.